# How can I protect laminated floor from casters on office chairs?

Tags: laminate-floor

How can I protect laminated floor from office chairs?
An acrylic mat looks ugly.  Can a rug end up damaging the floor too?

Comment: If dirt gets under the carpet the flooring can be damaged but I think it would be less than grit being ground in by the wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the casters on your chairs with "hardwood floor" casters.

[image: hardwood floor caster]

These have a rubberized edge instead of typical hard plastic. Should cost in the order of USD$20-40 per chair, and takes only a few minutes at most to replace.

It's cheaper than those acrylic mats, works everywhere (not just a 4x6' area), and doesn't look stupid (in fact you probably don't notice at all, especially if you get all black). They also make moving your chair a bit quieter.